# PDO::last Insert Id always return 0 use with MYSQL and prepare statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I cannot get last insert id from pdo connection, its always return 0. I have no solution please help me.
my function getConnection();

```
function getConnection(){
$servername="localhost";
$username="mmjadmin";
$password="gfam";
try{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=mmjdb",$username,$password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $conn; 
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Connect to database fail " . $e->getMessage();
}}
```

And I call this function to do on other function to insert data to

```
function insertUser($username,$password){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO T_Users(
                    username,
                    password,
                    regist_date,
                    update_date)
                VALUES(
                    :username,
                    :password,
                    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
    $stmt = getConnection()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':username',$username);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password',$password);
    $stmt->execute();
    $userid = getConnection()->lastInsertId();
}
```

I cannot get the last userid that I inserted that userid is autoincrement, it always return 0.

Comment: It's work now, unbelievable that do this. can you explain me? because it's look like same your code and my code.

Comment: I explained it in the answer. Don't call `getConnection()` more than once. And please accept my answer if it was helpful: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 6):

You alwas create a new connection, when you call `getConnection()`. You should store the connection and re-use it:

```
function insertUser($username,$password){
    $conn = getConnection();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO T_Users(
                    username,
                    password,
                    regist_date,
                    update_date)
                VALUES(
                    :username,
                    :password,
                    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':username',$username);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password',$password);
    $stmt->execute();
    $userid = $conn->lastInsertId();

    return $userId; // if needed
}
```

Comment: change this `$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);` to `$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);`

Comment: One last thing your function doesn't return last insert id please add this into your code

Comment: well it wasn't clear if the id was used outside the function or not, but i added the return ;)